# Redefining a called function from an imported module

Tags: python

So for example I have mod1.py:

```
def foo():
    bar()

def bar():
    print("This is bar in mod1")
```

And a mod2.py:

```
from mod1 import *

def bar():
    print("This is bar in mod2")
```

And then mod3.py:

```
import mod1
import mod2

mod1.foo()
mod2.foo()
```

After running mod3.py, I get the same output: "This is bar in mod1", even though I redefined it in mod2.py.

As far as I understand, when I call foo in mod2, it looks it up in mod1 since I imported it and didn't redefine it.

Is there a way I can make foo look for bar in mod2 instead of mod1?

Ofc without copying foo to mod2 or touching foo or bar in mod1 and be able to call them both in mod3, distinguished by their namespaces as in the mod3.py example.

Comment: You would be correct. mod2.foo() is pointing to mod1.foo() which is pointing to mod1.bar()

Comment: I don't think there is any way for `mod1.foo()` to see `mod2.bar()` without importing `mod2` into `mod1`.

Comment: Every function carries a reference to the global scope of the module in which it was defined. `mod1.foo` *always* calls `mod1.bar`, regardless of what `bar` might be defined in the global scope where `mod1.foo` is *called*.

Comment: So you will need to find another solution to the original problem that you are trying to solve with this technique.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will just use a class and overwrite the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too difficult, just pass in the `bar` explictly.

Which upon closer reading of the question is off limits as **mod1.py** can't be touched.  Oh well, leaving it still.

#### mod1.py

```
def bar():
    print("This is bar in mod1")

def foo(bar=bar):
    bar()
```

#### mod2.py is unchanged

#### mod3.py

```
import mod1
import mod2

mod1.foo()
mod2.foo()
mod2.foo(mod2.bar)
```

#### output:

```
This is bar in mod1
This is bar in mod1
This is bar in mod2
```

### update: without touching mod1's *source*:

Monkeypatching, more or less.  Thread safety?  Probably not.

```
import mod1
import mod2

mod1.foo()

ori_bar = mod1.bar

# I think this would be a good place for a context manager rather than 
# finally which needs adjustments to handle exceptions
try:
    mod1.bar = mod2.bar
    mod2.foo()
finally:
    mod1.bar = ori_bar

mod1.foo()
```

#### output:

```
This is bar in mod1
This is bar in mod2
This is bar in mod1
```

Terminology-wise, would the original `foo` implementation be considered as a *closure*?  Because I believe this specific behavior has been around for a long time in Python.

Comment: Passing bar is not really elegant and since one would need to save and restore the original function with every call with monkey patching, that's not convenient.
I will just rethink it with classes and overwrite the method. There is no easy way around this